# onAppearing method is called even tho that page is not appearing? Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a tabbed page and 3 content pages. On start of the app all three of the onAppearing() methods of the respectable content pages are called. Any way to disable this behavior? I want only the page that is first shown, execute the onAppearing() method.

Comment: This seems to be a design problem for the android platform. In native android, viewpager preloads its child pages when initialized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is impossible.A tabbed page loads all of its content pages at the start